# pandas: TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tresh'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I would like to remove rows with NaN values from my csv file using pandas. I want to remove rows where NaN values occur more than 2 times in my samples described as P1-25, P1-93 and so on.

Here is a part of my file:

```
  #CHROM   POS  ID REF ALT       QUAL  FILTER P1-25 P1-93 P1-88 P1-6 P1-89 P1-26 P1-12 P1-92 P1-22 P1-90 P1-28 P1-95
0   chr1  1152 NaN   G   A   1355.640     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
4   chr1  1331 NaN   A   C   4171.070     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/0   0/1   0/1
5   chr1  1349 NaN   T   C  11194.500     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
6   chr1  1401 NaN   T   G  10825.800     NaN   0/1   0/1   0/1  0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   0/1
7   chr1  2348 NaN   G   T    920.614     NaN   1/1   1/1   1/1  1/1   1/1   1/1   NaN   1/1   1/1   1/1   1/1   NaN
8   chr1  4045 NaN   G   T   1917.920     NaN   1/1   1/1   1/1  1/1   1/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1   0/1   1/1
```

And here is my script:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from less_memory_usage import remove_the_same_gt, to_csv

just_gt = remove_the_same_gt('data1.csv', 'data2.csv')
just_gt_nan = just_gt.replace('.', np.nan)
drop_dots = just_gt_nan.dropna(tresh=2,subset=['P1-25', 'P1-93', 'P1-88', 'P1-6', 'P1-89', 'P1-26', 'P1-12', 'P1-92', 'P1-22', 'P1-90', 'P1-28', 'P1-95'])
```

Unfortunately, it raises me such an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomasz/Pulpit/burak/finding_homozyg.py", line 31, in <module>
    'P1-22', 'P1-90', 'P1-28', 'P1-95'])
  File "/home/tomasz/miniconda3/envs/burak/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tresh'
```

I'm using pandas 1.3.4 version.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you meant to write `thresh`, right?

Comment: Oh sure, what a silly mistake! Thank you for the review!